# Apple watch short-look notification on simulator

Tags: storyboard, apple-watch

Is it possible to view a notification UI on apple watch like this in simulator? :

[image]

The full video is in this link:
http://www.misys.com/latest-insights/videos/misys-fusionbanking-essence-banktime/

I am only able view this notification UI in the simulator:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this question would fit better to other stackexchange forums?

Answer (score 0):

In simulator, you only can view the second one (long look), because short look doesn't have any special things, just the icon, the app name and the notification title.

But in long look, you can see title, text, icon, name and actionable buttons, so that is enough for testing the notification.

You can access the notification test by setting the target running to Notification - WatchKit App.